# reflect swf/swc for class that implements interface in actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, reflection, actionscript, flex3, flex4

Not sure if this is possible but I would like to reflect a swf or swc file selected by the user at runtime to find any classes that implement a certain interface.  Can this be done or do you actually need a reference to the class you want to reflect using describeType();

Note - this would be done in actionscript.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You can inspect a swf for the classnames ([Source](http://etcs.ru/pre/getDefinitionNamesSource/)) and then use describeType on them to find the ones which implement the interface(s). But this is probably slow. You can try to extend the `getDefinitionNames` code to get around the describeType and extract the needed info from the bytes...